# How do you go from capitize to lower case in Java, having troubles with my code output

Tags: java

In this starwars name generator code I am getting an output of:

> May the force be with you, PatSm BaSan

when it should be:

> May the force be with you, Patsm Basan.

here is my code for reference.

```
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Assignment2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.printf("Enter your first name: ");
        String firstname = input.nextLine().substring(0,3); 
        firstname = firstname.substring(0,1).toUpperCase() + firstname.substring(1).toLowerCase();

        System.out.printf("Enter your last name: ");
        String lastname = input.nextLine().substring(0,2);
        lastname = lastname.substring(0,1).toUpperCase() + lastname.substring(1).toLowerCase(); 

        System.out.printf("Enter your mother's maiden name: ");
        String mothersname = input.nextLine();
        mothersname = mothersname.substring(0,2);

        System.out.printf("Enter the name of the city in which you were born: ");
        String cityname = input.nextLine();
        cityname = cityname.substring(0,3);

        String StarWarsName = firstname+lastname+" "+mothersname+cityname;
        System.out.println("May the force be with you, " + StarWarsName );
    }
}
```

Comment: Part of solution have, what is your goal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at what you are doing to each of the strings when you read them.

```
firstname = firstname.substring(0,1).toUpperCase() + firstname.substring(1).toLowerCase();
```

This gives you the whole name in lowercase except the first letter. That's good.

```
lastname = lastname.substring(0,1).toUpperCase() + lastname.substring(1).toLowerCase();
```

But here, too, you're taking the whole last name in lowercase except the first letter. But this is not what you need - because this part will be in the *middle* of your star wars name. Instead, use:

```
lastname = lastname.toLowerCase();
```

Now the mother's name:

```
mothersname = mothersname.substring(0,2);
```

Capitalization is going to depend on whether or not the user entered the mother's name capitalized. So you should really use something like:

```
mothersname = mothersname.substring(0,1).toUpperCase() + mothersname.substring(1,2).toLowerCase();
```

Finally, the city:

```
cityname = cityname.substring(0,3);
```

Again, the capitalization depends on whether the user entered it with a capital or not (which he probably did), and you want it to be all lowercase because it's going to be concatenated to the part of the mother's name. So:

```
cityname = cityname.substring(0,3).toLowerCase();
```

Once you make all those fixes, your name will come up fine at the end.

Comment: Thanks just ran it, I changed `mothersname.substring(0,1).toUpperCase() + mothersname.substring(1,1).toLowerCase();` to `mothersname.substring(0,1).toUpperCase() + mothersname.substring(1,2).toLowerCase();`

Comment: @patm Ah, yes, my mistake.

Comment: Thanks for the help..was stuck on that issue for quite sometime

Answer (score 2):

You cause the lastname to start with a capital letter by using toUpperCase() on the first letter of it.

You could easily fix the cases for the variable `StarWarsName`. Try:

```
String correctName = "";
for (int i = 0; i < starWarsName.length(); i++) {
   if (i == 0 || starWarsName.charAt(i - 1) == ' ')
       correctName += starWarsName.substring(i, i + 1).toUpperCase();
   else
       correctName += starWarsName.substring(i, i + 1).toLowerCase();
}
```

Also you should start variable names with a lower case letter. ;)

Comment: tried that and I got the error `Cannot invoke toLowerCase() on the primitive type char`

Comment: Ah, my bad. Use `starWarsName.substring(i, i+1).toLowerCase()` instead.

Comment: Yes, I hardly have to use String manipulation with `toLowerCase()` or `toUpperCase()`, which is why I totally overlooked that fact. I updated my answer so that it now works.